# issues with <g:each> tag iteration in Grails

Tags: grails, dynamic, tags, dns, each

I'm new to grails and I am trying to display all the data of a domain class from the database in a table. When I open the gsp file my table is blank. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong since I have been following every tutorial exactly with the same syntax. My domain class name is "Test" and here is my code for the table:

```
        <g:each var="test" in="${tests}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ${test.testName}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${test.numberofQuestions}
            </td>
            <td>
                ${test.responseType}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
```

Comment: To troubleshoot, we need more information.  What is the directory/filename of the gsp you have shown an what controller/method is outputing your tests variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to bring back all of your "Test" domain objects you would do something like this:

```
<g:each var="test" in="${com.mypackage.Test.list()}">
```

or

```
<g:each var="test" in="${com.mypackage.Test.listOrderByTestName()}">
```

if you wanted them in order by `testName` (be sure to use the actual package name in place of `com.mypackage`).

If you are trying to pass a `tests` variable into the GSP to be used as jonaldomo said in the comment we will need more information.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I included the package name and the list() method and it works great.